# Auto-copying OTP to clipboard from SMS doesn't work when using the website in my app's web view but works when used in browser

Tags: android, flutter, android-webview, android-permissions

The app is a flutter app with most of the functionality inside `InAppWebView`. This issue of OTP from SMS not being copied into clipboard exists only on the android side.

What could be the cause of the issue? A missing permission or missing option for the web view? Or something else?

These are the options used for the web view, in case they matter:

```
return InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
    useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
    javaScriptEnabled: true,
  ),
  android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
    useHybridComposition: true,
    supportMultipleWindows: true,
  ),
  ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
    allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
    applePayAPIEnabled: _applePayEnabled,
  ),
);
```